# VPN and Remote Desktop Stopped Working (Windows Server 2008 R2)

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop, remote-desktop-services

Recently, both the VPN and remote desktop stopped working.  See below for details.

**VPN:**

- `Error 800: The remote connection was not made because the attempted VPN tunnels failed. The VPN server might be unreachable. If this connection is attempting to use an...`

**Remote Desktop:**

- Still accessible from within LAN
- Gets stuck on `Configuring remote session...` from outside the network

From what I've gathered, every other service is working perfectly.  All ports appear to be forwarding properly, and I can access the various web interfaces that are served via that server.  This issue seems to be centered around the VPN and remote desktop feature.  I have tried restarting different services, and did a physical reboot.

Any ideas, links, etc., would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** The Remote Desktop functionality works when VPN is disabled.  The utter randomness of this is frustrating!

Comment: Barring any firewall changes, I would reboot your firewall and/or router.

Comment: Hi joeqwerty, No firewall changes in Windows Server, or the router.  Already reboot router and server itself.

Answer (score 0):

You might check to see if any recent firewall changes have taken place.

Comment: What happens when you telnet to the RDP port from outside your network?

Comment: Good call. Telnet seems to indicate it is getting through (no connect failed message or anything like that).

Comment: But what is actually being displayed?

Comment: Your standard blinking cursor

Comment: Then something else is probably intercepting the ssh session, you might compare it to a session from within your network.

Comment: Works fine from within the network. How can I get more information on what is happening inside vs. outside?

Comment: Map out the equipment that is between the two pathing configurations and check at the additional points/equipment. It's probably your router, firewall or ISP.